# Add custom error message for extra field in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, input-field

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails application, I'm using Devise for user authentication, I added an extra field in the form and now I would like to add custom error message for this field (Please enter correct battletag with format John#123), if a user inputs incorrect battletag format in the field.

Some solutions suggested that you should add message in en.yml but I can't understand where to make the change.

```
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :battletag %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :battletag, autofocus: true, 
                  pattern: '[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,11}#[0-9]+',
                  placeholder: 'Johndoe#123'  %>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do stuff like this in the model, so I guess in `User.rb`, assuming your model is named `User`.

```
validates :battletag, format: { with: /[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,11}#[0-9]+/, :message => 'Please enter correct battletag with format John#123'}
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format